# Why can't I store a modified list in a new variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not looking for a solution, but more of an explanation as to why the output is None

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list2 = list1.remove(3)

print(list2)
```

Expected Output:

```
[1,2,4,5]
```

Actual Output:

```
None
```

Comment: `list1.remove` is an inplace operation. Hence it will always return `None`

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `remove` would *return a new list minus the removed element*?

Comment: You can get a list output using `filter()`. `list(filter(lambda a: a != 3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))` will return the list `[1, 2, 4, 5]`, not `None`. Or, you can choose to use list comprehension.

Comment: because the **remove()** always return **None**, you can do something like this `list2 = list1.remove(3) or list1`, it stores the **list1** except  removed element in list2. however when ever you use `list1.remove(element)` it removes the element from the **list1** too.

Answer (score 1):

[remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does not return a new list, the modification happens on the list itself.

Your code works, but you should print the first list.

```py
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list1.remove(3)
>>> print(list1)
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```